# Listening MIDI Events from MIDI file (Audiokit)

Tags: ios, swift, midi, audiokit

I am trying to build a rhythm game with SwiftUI and SpriteKit for iOS devices and I'm stuck with a problem regarding midi. I am trying to trigger an event based on the note currently playing when I play a MIDI file. I play the MIDI File with AVMIDIPlayer and try to listen events with AudioKit MIDIListener. However the function receivedMIDINoteOn in the listener never triggers when I play the file.

Here is a test code to demonstrate my problem. So on the touch of the screen, a midi file is played but the MIDIReceiver doesn't detect it, it does however detect the line  "self.midi.sendNoteOnMessage(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 127)" which I put there for test purposes.

```
class MidiPlayer: ObservableObject {

    let midiFile: URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "no_name" , withExtension: "mid")!
    var midi = MIDI()
    
    var midiPlayer: AVMIDIPlayer?
    func playFile() {
        do {
            self.midi.openOutput()
            try midiPlayer = AVMIDIPlayer(contentsOf: midiFile as URL, soundBankURL: nil)
            midiPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
            
        } catch {
            print("could not create MIDI player")
        }
        self.midi.sendNoteOnMessage(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 127)
        midiPlayer?.play {
            
            print("finished playing")
        }
    }
}


class MIDIReceiver: MIDIListener, ObservableObject {
    static let instance = MIDIReceiver()

    var midi = MIDI()

    
    func connectInputs() {
        print("connecting devices")

        midi.openInput()

        midi.addListener(self)


    }

    func receivedMIDINoteOn(noteNumber: AudioKit.MIDINoteNumber, velocity: AudioKit.MIDIVelocity, channel: AudioKit.MIDIChannel, portID: MIDIUniqueID?, timeStamp: MIDITimeStamp?) {
        print("okay3")
        print(String(noteNumber))

    }
    
    func receivedMIDINoteOff(noteNumber: AudioKit.MIDINoteNumber, velocity: AudioKit.MIDIVelocity, channel: AudioKit.MIDIChannel, portID: MIDIUniqueID?, timeStamp: MIDITimeStamp?) {
        print("okay4")

    }
    
    
    
}

struct GameView: View {
    @StateObject var midi = MIDIReceiver()
    
    var scene: SKScene {
        let scene = GameScene()
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 800, height: 600)
        scene.scaleMode = .fill
        return scene
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SpriteView(scene: scene)
                .frame(width: 800, height: 600)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }.onAppear(perform: {
            midi.connectInputs()

        })
    }
        
    

}


class GameScene: SKScene {
    var player = MidiPlayer()


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        player.playFile()

    }
    
}
```

I'm sorry if this is a very basic question, I am a beginner dev. Thanks for reading!